# The website is continue loading at 0% when testing a Facebook instant game on https server

Tags: facebook, typescript

Sorry for my bad English, I do the thing(test my project) just like in the official document(https://developers.facebook.com). I test my cert with commands, no errors. When I made a https server, there were also no errors. You can find the project here: developers.facebook.com.

Firstly, I test `localhost:8080`, it shows me unsafe and https is red, when the project is embed, yeah,the url is `https://www.facebook.com/embed/instantgames/YOUR_GAME_ID/player?game_url=https://localhost:8080` and this tim the website seems not to work, it continues loading at 0%. I don't know why. Could someone please help me? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hello How Soon. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not answerable in its current format. Please check that your certificate is valid for the domain you are using and that it is issued by a CA trusted by the parties involved.

Comment: Hi Fenton,i am so happy that your apply is so fast,because it is firtst time i got an answer from a sharp(i do not know this word is good or bad,but i mean good), i just check my certificate with  " openssl verify cert.pem" and i got OK,this time i will try CA,i remember the domain is facebook.com or localhost,any way ,i will try,thanks very much,haha

Comment: Have you first of all checked the browser console for error messages in that regard? If there aren’t any in relation to this, then I’d check what exactly goes on with the request in the network panel.

Comment: Hi CBroe,i just checked the console,there is no log at all,and i found my cert is self signature ,is that a problem?? i am not sure.i also check the network panel,it seems alright,my browser is chrome

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually inform the API that you are done loading. The minimum code can be found on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart), and looks like this:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
FBInstant.initializeAsync()
  .then(function() {        

  });

// Once all assets are loaded, tells the SDK 
// to end loading view and start the game
FBInstant.startGameAsync()
  .then(function() {
    // Retrieving context and player information can only be done
    // once startGameAsync() resolves
    var contextId = FBInstant.context.getID();
    var contextType = FBInstant.context.getType();

    var playerName = FBInstant.player.getName();
    var playerPic = FBInstant.player.getPhoto();
    var playerId = FBInstant.player.getID();

    // Once startGameAsync() resolves it also means the loading view has 
    // been removed and the user can see the game viewport

    game.start();
  });
</script>
```